# MyBatis Error with less than equal to and greater than equal symbols

Tags: sql, mybatis

I am working a fix to one sql query to include a where clause with less than equal and greater than equal in a case statement but whenever I try to run I get the same error message saying the <= token was not valid. I have tried the symbols as both html code and wrapped in CDATA brackets both give the same error. The mybatis queue is below.

```
    WHERE A.WDATE BETWEEN  #{fdate} AND #{tdate}
    AND A.FAC LIKE #{fac}

    <if test = 'good != "%"'>
        AND SUBSTR(A.ITDSC,21,4) NOT LIKE  #{good}
    </if>
    <if test = 'size != ""'>
        AND CASE WHEN #{size} = '16' THEN SUBSTR(A.ITDSC,13,2) &lt;= '16'   ELSE SUBSTR(A.ITDSC,13,2) &gt;= '17' END
    </if>
```

Comment: Reduce your query to the core problem and format it readable please.

Comment: I will do that now

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Using DB2 I can get it to run if I use a sql program but it causes a error when I put the statement in mybatis

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 3):

Escaping `<=` and `>=` with `&lt;=` and `&gt;=` looks OK and works for me.

But that part of the where-clause

```
AND 
  CASE 
     WHEN #{size} = '16' THEN SUBSTR(A.ITDSC,13,2) &lt;= '16'   
     ELSE SUBSTR(A.ITDSC,13,2) &gt;= '17' 
  END
```

looks suspicious.

In `DB2` the `CASE` has to be part of an expression, e.g.

```
WHERE xyz >= CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END
```

or

```
 WHERE
     (CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END) >= xyz
```

See [case-expressions](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/ibmdb2/w/wiki/7601.case-expressions) for more info and examples.

Comment: I tried your method but I gave me the same error message about less than symbol not being valid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, maybe work;)

```
WHERE A.WDATE BETWEEN  #{fdate} AND #{tdate}
AND A.FAC LIKE #{fac}

<if test = 'good != "%"'>
AND SUBSTR(A.ITDSC,21,4) NOT LIKE  #{good}
</if>
<if test = 'size != ""'>
AND ((#{size} = '16' AND SUBSTR(A.ITDSC,13,2) &lt;= '16') OR SUBSTR(A.ITDSC,13,2) &gt;= '17')
</if>
```

Comment: You suggested fixed the error but it caused another error. This is the Message:                                                                                                                                                                             java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: @Demilich1988  Is this error caused by executing the DAO layer code?

Comment: @Demilich1988 Or maybe when Mybatis's result set mapped to entity, and a `String` is casted into a `Integer` in your query code, then this exception happened. I thought;)

Comment: Not sure where the Error was coming cause it was mapped to a String all the results to that queue were mapped to a string.

Comment: @Demilich1988 Have you done with this problem? Or Could you give me more exception stacktrace from your console log.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by using two IF statements for size one for size =='16' and the other for size=='17'